# Unable to understand a piece of code for 3D model deform

Tags: python, 3d-rendering

I'm having trouble reading a piece of sample code for a model deformation.

The goal of the sample code is to optimize the model geometry through a backpropagation algorithm, which allows us to transform an initial model into a model that we need.

However, in the forward process, the sample code first **transforms** the initial node coordinates: including the definitions of `self.center`, `self.displace`, and uses `log`, `tanh`, `sigmoid`, `relu` and other functions. What is the significance of these transformations, and why not take the original node coordinates as the initial value and optimize them directly?

The forward part is as follows:

```
    def execute(self, batch_size):
        base = jt.log(self.vertices.abs() / (1 - self.vertices.abs()))
        centroid = jt.tanh(self.center)
        vertices = (base + self.displace).sigmoid() * nn.sign(self.vertices)
        vertices = nn.relu(vertices) * (1 - centroid) - nn.relu(-vertices) * (centroid + 1)
        vertices = vertices + centroid
```

where `self.vertices` is the original node coordinates. And `self.center` and `self.displace` are two newly defined parameters.

```
    # optimize for displacement map and center
    self.displace = jt.zeros(self.template_mesh.vertices.shape)
    self.center = jt.zeros((1, 1, 3))
```

The link of the code: https://github.com/Jittor/jrender. in "Basic tutorial 2: Geometry Optimization", `demo2-deform.py`

Comment: Maybe you should address your questions to the author of the code.  There could be many reasons, why the author elected to perform these transformations, leading to speculation and opinion on our part.